# Formalize "Statement $A$ is the correct explanation of statement $B$"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If I have two statements. Let say Statement $A$ and Statement $B$.

What will be the necessary condition or how to write the following conditions mathematically?

Statement $A$ is the correct explanation of statement $B$.

Comment: As is often the case, it cannot be done. No combination of truth-functional connectives can capture the connotations of the ordinary language sentence at the end of the post.

Comment: While Andre's comment is correct, there are certainly statements that come close.  One at least plausible rough translation is 'A is true, B can be derived from A, and the complexity of (A plus the proof of B from A) is smallest among all sentences which imply B'.  This shows up in complexity theory under the name _Minimum Description Length_ : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_description_length

Comment: @AndréNicolas is there any reason for it?

Comment: The truth values of $A$ and $B$ are (informally) not enough to determine whether $A$ is **the** correct explanation of $B$. For example suppose it is true that i($A$) t rained last night. Then this might be reasonably viewed as the correct explanation that the ground is wet ($B$). But $1=1$ ($A'$) is also true. It would not be reasonable to think of $A'$ as the correct explanation of $B$. That said, you can probably figure out what they **intend** you to write as the "correct" answer. It involves an implication.